# Не работает метод add в ArrayList

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

Есть готовый код класса коллекции. Он работает.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BallCollection {
    static ArrayList<Ball> list = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    public static void add (Ball b) {
        list.add(b);
    }

    public static void moveBalls (float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        for (Ball ball : list) {
            ball.offset(deltaX, deltaY);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Ball> getPredators() {
        ArrayList<Ball> predators = new ArrayList<Ball>();
        for (Ball ball : list) {
            if (ball.isPredator() && ball.isActive()) {
                predators.add(ball);
            }
        }   
        return predators;
    }

    public static void update (int ms) {
        for (Ball ball : list) {
            ball.update(ms);
        }
    }

    public static void paint (Graphics g) {
        for (Ball ball : list) {
            ball.paint(g);
        }
    }

    public static void checkCollision (Ball b) {
        for (Ball ball : list) {
            if (ball.isActive() && ball.isEdible()) {
                if (ball.intersects(b)) {
                    b.eat(ball);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Есть попытки в другом проекте создать аналогичный класс:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CreatureColl {
    static ArrayList<Robot> list = new ArrayList<Robot>();

    public static void add (Robot r) {
        list.add(r);
    }
}
```

Он также не содержит ошибок.
Но при добавлении объекта в коллекцию появляются 4 ошибки.

```
Robot player = new Robot(100, 100);
Robot bot1 = new Robot(200, 200);
CreatureColl.add(player);
```

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token  Panel.java  /Robots/src line 22 Java Problem
>   Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration  Panel.java  /Robots/src line 22 Java Problem
>   Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName    Panel.java  /Robots/src line 22 Java Problem
>   Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName Panel.java  /Robots/src line 22 Java Problem

Comment: `Он также не содержит ошибок` - если бы там не было ошибок, то вашего вопроса тут не было)))))) ...............уверен, что вы от нас что-о скрыли и не всё показали. И это что-то: наличие некоторого исполняемого кода прямо в классе, вместо метода.....ну или просто что-то лишнее где-то проставлено......... для подтверждения моих слов можете опубликовать весь код класса Robot и весь код класса CreatureColl....... и класс где написаны эти три строки `Robot player = new Robot(100,100);
Robot bot1 = new Robot(200,200);
CreatureColl.add(player);` вангую что проблема в нем

Comment: В тексте ошибки сказано, что ошибка в строке 22 в классе Panel.java. Где эта строка в представленном вами коде?